# Fatal error: Class 'OCP\AutoloadNotAllowedException' not found in C:\wamp\www\owncloud\lib\autoloader.php on line 138

Tags: cloud, dropbox, owncloud

While using 'owncloud' on wamp server I am facing these error please help me out..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Owncloud 8.1.x there is no support for Windows as a host. There are two sides but the first is ... it's a failed by concept for a software to use by private end users at home. Linux is not an option for everyone.

Comment: Try to use the unsupported owncloud version 7.0.14: https://download.owncloud.org/community/owncloud-7.0.14.tar.bz2!